# SQL LIKE command doesn't work with strings containing dots

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing an (My)SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM releases
WHERE version LIKE '12.3%'
```

I want all subversions of 12.3 but it gives me nothing (though there are such records). If I instead write 12% then it works. I guess I will have to escape the dots or...?

Comment: How are your versions stored (show us some samples)? There's no reason that this wouldn't find any subversions.

Comment: What is the data type of your `version` column?

Comment: @Constantine LIKE does not use regexp http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: [Works as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc35fa/2). Can you provide a full self-contained example?

Comment: Can you show us a few rows that should be returned - but are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `releases`
WHERE version REGEXP '^12\.[0-9]+$'
```

Not sure but releases might be a reserved word.

Comment: You will need to escape the `.` from being a wildcard.

Answer (score 1):

I've created this:

```
create table app (id varchar(10));
```

I've filled these:

```
insert into app values
('1.10'), ('1.1'), ('1.2'),
('1.3'), ('1.4'), ('1.5'),
('2.1'), ('2.2'), ('2.3'),
('2.4');
```

I've selected these:

```
select * from app where id like '1.1%';
```

The result is two rows
1.10
and 1.1

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bead8/1/0)

Have you stored your value as a number instead of a string?